# Don't know if I'm using Firebase JS SDK or React-Native-Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I've created a large web app using Firebase's JS SDK, and now I'm transition to a mobile app using React-Native, Expo. Since I'm using Expo, I've created a development client so that I don't use Expo Go, as RNFirebase uses native code.
**My Goal: Implement basic Google login that links with React-Native-Firebase authentication**

I've npm installed"react-native-firebase/app""react-native-firebase/auth"

However, when I tried to do authentication using Google's signin (https://rnfirebase.io/auth/social-auth), I kept getting an error saying that '[DEFAULT]' firebase app wasn't initialized.

So, I followed another guide, which (I don't know if it's right), told me to create a firebase.js file like my web app that did:

```
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';

import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional

const firebaseConfig = {apiKey: "AIzaSyCoNUZI0-Mir9hGtXUJJmIrML88JxSOJAk",authDomain: "campus-market-25068.firebaseapp.com",databaseURL: "https://campus-market-25068-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",projectId: "campus-market-25068",storageBucket: "campus-market-25068.appspot.com",messagingSenderId: "315015080294",appId: "1:315015080294:web:53dbed097963d67b92c0a7",measurementId: "G-5TVXC2MQ7S"};if (!firebase.apps.length) {firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);}export { firebase, auth }
```

Now, the authentication works, but I don't know if I'm still using RNFirebase or if I'm using Firebase's JS SDK. Could anyone answer? This is my authentication code:

```
import 'expo-dev-client'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
// import './src/firebase';/
/ import * as firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';
import { auth } from './firebase';
import { GoogleSignin } from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin';
export default function App() {
GoogleSignin.configure({
webClientId: '315015080294-gejpuoaedqhbcve32dat55gg4cn5va3j.apps.googleusercontent.com',
});

async function onGoogleButtonPress() {
// Check if your device supports Google Play
await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices({ showPlayServicesUpdateDialog: true });
// Get the users ID token
console.log(GoogleSignin);
const { idToken } = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);
// Sign-in the user with the credential
return auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);// console.log("YOOOOOOO5")// console.log(res)}



return (
<View style={styles.container}><Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text><StatusBar style="auto" /><Buttontitle="Google Sign-In"onPress={() => onGoogleButtonPress().then(() => console.log('Signed in with Google!'))}/></View>);})
)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({container: {flex: 1,backgroundColor: '#fff',alignItems: 'center',justifyContent: 'center',},});
```

I'm not sure where to start

Answer (score 0):

Given the `auth().signInWithCredential` in this line of code, you are still using the `react-native-firebase` library:

```
return auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
```

In the Firebase JavaScript SDK this would either be `firebase.auth().signInWithCredential` or `signInWithCredential(auth, ...`.

Comment: that makes sense. but then, if I'm only using react-native-firebase, then why do I need to include the firebase.js with the firebase config and initializeApp in order for auth to work?
I thought that as long as I have a google-services.json file, then I wouldnt need a firebase config

Comment: I guess that might be because of `if (!firebase.apps.length) {firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);}`. But honestly, it's hard to say - the code is quite hard to read with the lack of formatting, and the second code blocks seems to be syntactically incorrect (hence the code highlighting being off for most of it).